# (Java) I am making a horizontal Ruler with for loops

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a horizontal ruler as shown below:

The code I have right now is:

```
public class JavaRuler {
    public static final int COUNT = 19;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Design();
        Inches();
        Number();
    }

    public static void Design() {

        for (int j = 1; j <= COUNT * 2 + 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("__");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void Inches() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT * 2 + 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("'|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void Number() {
        for (int k = 1; k <= COUNT; k++) {
            System.out.print("___" + k);
        }   
    }
}
```

The ruler has to be re-sizable in inches and if statements are not allowed (only for loops) my current output is really close but I cant seem to figure out how to decrease the "_" in the third row once the numbers go beyond 9. Any tips?

Comment: Convert the string to an int, substring the prefix based on the length of that int

Comment: A side note : see [Java Naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 2):

I think my example here will do the trick

```
public static void Number() {
    for (int k = 1; k <= COUNT; k++) {
      System.out.print(("____" + k).substring(("" + k).length()));
    }
}
```

Result

```
'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|
___1___2___3___4___5___6___7___8___9__10__11__12__13__14__15__16__17__18__19
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this, but the result will be a mess if the `COUNT` is a big number. I have also updated some of your codes so that the `inches` and `design` will not overlap the last number.

```
public class JavaRuler {
    public static final int COUNT = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Design(" ");
        Inches();
        Number();
        Design("|");
    }

    public static void Design(String s) { // Added parameter
        System.out.print(s + "_"); // Added
        for (int j = 0; j < COUNT * 2; j++) { // Updated
            System.out.print("__");
        }
        System.out.print(s); // Added
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void Inches() {
        System.out.print("|"); // Added
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT * 2; i++) { // Updated
            System.out.print("'|");
        }
        System.out.print("'|"); // Added
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void Number() {
        System.out.print("|"); // Added
        for (int k = 1; k <= COUNT; k++) {
            String underScore = "   "; // Added
            int length = (int) (Math.log10(k - 1) + 1); 
            for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                underScore = underScore.replaceFirst(" ", ""); // Added
            }
            System.out.print(underScore + k); // Updated
        }
        System.out.print("|"); // Added
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Result:

```
 _________________________________________________________________________________ 
|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|'|
|   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20|
|_________________________________________________________________________________|
```

Answer (score 1):

I came back to it later today and it hit me! I figured it out!

```
public class Ruler {
public static final int COUNT = 19;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Design();
    Inches();
    Numbers();
}

public static void Design() {

    for (int j = 1; j <= COUNT * 2 + 2; j++) {
        System.out.print("__");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void Inches() {
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT * 2 + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("'|");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("");
}

public static void Numbers() {
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
        System.out.print("___" + k);
    }
    System.out.print("___");
    for (int m = 10; m <= COUNT; m++){
        System.out.print(m + "__");
        }
    System.out.print("|");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it won't work if the `COUNT` has more than 2 digits(100?). And it won't work it the `COUNT` is less than 9 (5 for example).